# How to add multiple run in parallelStagesMap in declarative pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, pipeline

```
def jobs = [
    [
        "name" : "LegacyUnitTests",
        "runFolder" : "recipes",
        "run"   : { -> sh "docker-compose -f docker-compose/docker-compose-maven.yml -f docker-compose/docker-compose.yml run maven-unit-test" },
        "report": { -> junit testResults: "docker-compose/volmnt/reports/*.xml" },
    ],
    [
        "name" : "AutomationTests",
        "runFolder" : "automation",
        "run"   : { -> sh "../run_automation_tests.sh" },
        "report": { ->
            junit testResults: "reports/junit/*.xml"
            allure([
                includeProperties: false,
                jdk: '',
                properties: [],
                reportBuildPolicy: 'ALWAYS',
                results: [[path: '/reports/allure']]
            ])
        }
    ]
]

def parallelStagesMap = jobs.collectEntries {
    ["${it.name}" : generateStage(it)]
}

def generateStage(job) {
    return {
        stage(job.name) {
            dir(job.runFolder) {
                try {
                    job.run.call()
                    setSuccess(this, job.name)
                }
                catch (err) {
                    setFailed(this, job.name)
                }
            }
       }
   }
}

pipeline {
    agent {
        node {
            label 'pr-slave-test'
            customWorkspace "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/${JOB_NAME}_${BUILD_NUMBER}"
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
            //Reports
            script {
                jobs.each {
                    j -> j.report.call()
                }
            }//Cleanup
            cleanWs()
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Pre-Build') {
            steps {
                 script {
                    //set status as pending
                    jobs.each {
                        j -> setPending(this, j.name)
                    }
                    //checkout all repo   
                 }
            }
        }
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                dir () {
                    sh "echo \"Building\""
                }
            }
        }
        stage('CI') {
            steps {
                script {
                    parallel parallelStagesMap
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have a declarative pipeline like this and we are running the jobs defined in the jobs map in parallel. I have a requirement now to split and run our unit tests in parallel and i wish to implement that without adding another entry in jobs map instead i like to add another **`"run"`** in the LegacyUnitTests entry itself and run the "run" codes in parallel. Can someone help me how to achieve this?